# Rails - Issue with permitting params & require

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with submitting my params,

`portrait` and `portrait_tag` are passed through my form and are siblings, 
how would I go permitting both of these?

**Output**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"", "portrait"=>{"artist_image"= "", @original_filename="rubytraining.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg"}, "portrait_tag"=>{"tag_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "controller"=>"admin/portraits", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"72"}
```

I've tried the following

```
private
def portrait_params
    params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, :artist_image)
    params.require(:portrait_tag).permit(:id, :tag => [])
end
```

These work separately but overwrite one another when added together

controller

```
def update

      @portrait = Portrait.where(artist_id: 33, id: params[:id]).take

      if @portrait.update(portrait_params)

        redirect_to :edit_admin_portrait, flash: {notice: "Successfully updated your information"}

      else
        flash[:system] = @portrait.errors.full_messages
        p @portrait.errors.full_messages

        render :edit
      end

    end

private
def portrait_params
    params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, :artist_image)
    params.require(:portrait_tag).permit(:id, :tag => [])
end
```

**Edit Form**

```
%h1 Edit Portrait
= form_for [:admin, @portraits] do |f|

  - if flash[:system].present?
    - flash[:system].each do |e|
      %div= e

  - if flash[:notice].present?
    %div= flash[:notice]

  = f.file_field :artist_image


  = collection_select :portrait_tag, :tag_ids,  Tag.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @portraits.tag_ids}, { :multiple => true}

  = f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Do you need them in the same hash at the same time? What for?

Comment: When editing the form and the artist image is updated and the tags are updated at the same time.

Comment: Show the controller action. I kinda doubt it's "at the same time".

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I've added it

Comment: Yes, that's a valid code for when you only need `:portrait` params. Where's the code that saves the tags? What I mean to say, what do you expect output of `portrait_params` to be and why?

Comment: the tags are an association of the portrait (portrait_tags). They get updated with the model when it is saved

When the params are passed I would expect portrait tags to update and also the portrait model to update.

Comment: You didn't answer the last question. You're trying to do that weird double permit, but it doesn't return what you expect. What do you expect it to return? Also, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the tags are an association of the portrait (portrait_tags).

Finally, the core of the problem. In this case, you should be using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). It will allow you to post attributes for tags inside your `:portrait` params.

So your strong params method would look like this:

```
def portrait_params
  params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, :artist_image, portrait_tags_attributes: [:id, :tag])
end
```

Of course, amend your forms accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I've added my form also for more clarity

Comment: @Adam: yeah, I had a pretty good idea what your form looked like. :)

Comment: Should my collection_select be a part of the form_for loop? for instance f.collection_select? or can I still use portrait_tags_attributes irregardless of whether it's in the child loop?

Comment: @Adam: `form_for` is not a loop. But yes, your tags select should be in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning only last line of portrait_params.

```
params.require(:portrait_tag).permit(:id, :tag => [])
```

I'd do it like this:
Make two private methods with params`(portrait, portrait_tag)` , they will return you Hash'es, then you can merge them. It is not clear to have method portrait_params which return you 
portrait_tag params if they are not in nested attributes.
If they are you can use but you have to add this to model
[method accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)
and then you can do it like this

```
def portrait_params
  params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, :artist_image, portrait_tags_attributes: [:id, :tag]))
end
```

Comment: Thanks @argonus, I've also added my edit form to help better understand the situation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested_attributes to update parent and child same time. But you have to made some changes, for instance you need to change params structure.

Ex:

```
params.require(:portrait).permit(:attr1,:att2,..., portrait_attributes: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

Ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html